# "Microsoft sdx helper stopped working" with Office 365 and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, office365, microsoft-office-2019

In the past weeks several of our office computers running Windows 7 64bits and Microsoft Office 365 are randomly displaying the error message "Microsoft sdx helper stopped working". This does not have a severe impact as none of the office applications is closed when this happens, but it is annoying and our ticket tracking system is being flooded by this.

We've tried the following without success:

- Office quick repair
- Office online repair
- Reinstall with another version (x86 -> x64)
- Check for any missing updates for Windows
- Disable Office updates from the File menu

The versions of office installed range from 16.0.12026.20100 to 16.0.12026.20312 and we have computers affected independent of having the office 32bits or 64bits version installed.

I don't know why some of the users are not seeing this message. Maybe they use office applications less often. We've tried to isolate any other variable to understand why it is not happening in every single Windows 7 PC without success.

Any ideas besides upgrading to windows 10?

Comment: To start with, you need to upgrade to Windows 10. You may not prefer that answer, but Windows 7 is ancient, by any reasonable measure, and problems, errors, and security issues are to be expected if you insist on continuing to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: We've found out that this was being triggered by 2 scheduled tasks that run this program. They are located in Task Scheduler\Microsoft\Office and are called:

- Office Feature Updates Logon - runs when a user logs on
- Office Feature Updates - runs every day at 2:10, 6:10, 10:10, 14:10, 18:10 and 22:10

Disabling this tasks seems to stop the error from appearing but it prevents at least some kind of office updates (see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/licensing/office-feature-updates-task-faq).

We've recently found out that this is not a final fix as some office updates reenable these tasks. Here's a dirty script to disable the 2 tasks when OS is Win 7:

```
setlocal
for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set VERSION=%%i.%%j
if "%version%" == "6.1" {
    schtasks.exe /change /tn "Microsoft\Office\Office Feature Updates Logon" /disable
    schtasks.exe /change /tn "Microsoft\Office\Office Feature Updates" /disable
}
endlocal
```